# Is a $3D$ volume possible with only $3$ faces?

Tags: geometry, 3d, noneuclidean-geometry

I was wondering if a $3D$ volume with only $3$ faces was possible. I know that in the Euclidean space, it is technically not possible (the minimum being $4$ faces), but maybe there was some other way.

Like the moebius strip that only has one side and one face.

Maybe by bending the space?

Thank you!

Comment: You certainly mean more than three points. Three points are just three points, having no dimension at all.

Comment: Do you mean something like: "Can I define a unique 3D volume with only three vertices?"

Comment: You are right, I edited my question. Changed vertices to faces. I was sleepy I guess.

Comment: Interesting. I can't immediately supply a proof of the 2d version - in a plane, two lines can't enclose a bounded area.

Comment: If you allow curved faces, than a single face can do.

Comment: sure if you allow bending of surface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prepared this image for the version of your question asking for a volume with *three vertices*, which emphasizes mathreadler's comment "sure if you allow bending of surface":

[image]

A version with three faces is obtained by intersecting three spheres:

[image]

If you do not want to have bent faces, but you allow infinite faces: imagine a trianglular pyramid that extends infinitely in one direction. It has three faces only.

If you want to avoid bent and infinite faces, you might find a solution in sphereical geometries similar to the one in my second picture. I think that in spherical geometries, the bent faces of this shape are actually intrisically "flat" because bounded by great circles. Not completely sure though.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have a polyhedron with $3$ (planar) faces $F_i = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^3:\, x.\xi_i = a_i\}$ for some $\xi_i$ of norm $1$ and some $a_i$. The result is trivial if any distinct $\xi_i$ agree (i.e., if two of the faces are parallel); otherwise, there exists some $g\in O(3)$ mapping $(\xi_1, \xi_2, \xi_3)$ to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Such an action preserves volume (modulo sign), so we're left with the case where the faces are parallel to the coordinate axes. The same argument works in arbitrary $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Do you have some ressource to show me the way of understanding what you just wrote? It's a bit too advanced for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something really cool, make a torus with *one* face.

Start with a hexagon in which opposite sides are congruent and parallel, for example by cutting opposite corners from a parallelogram.  For ease of manipulation one pair of opposite sides should be much longer than the other two pairs.

Glue the long sides together so they become a single joint, with the other pairs of sides forming the jagged ends of a tube.  Now give one end of the tube a half-twist and bend the ends together.  You need to do some stretching and squeezing to get the fits exact, for you are creating a noneuclidean surface, but you end up with a torus derived from one hexagonal face!

For a video deminstration see [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=-be1ABH-ONM).

Comment: Do you have a visual example? I thought a torus by definition had one face.